# Two questions about SOIL, OpenGL and GLUT

Tags: c, opengl, 2d, collision-detection, glut

Two questions about these three:

1. How can you load only a PART of an image in a texture (GLuint) using SOIL. I can load a full PNG picture but I can't figure out how to load only a PART of it. As in animations. for example [HERE](http://www.luxinia.de/uploads/Tutorials/explosprite.png) which is an animation of a shooting catapult. How do I load only a part of it ? (With known location of pixels needed for that part).
2. How to do Pixel-per-pixel collision detection using `glReadPixels();`? I succeeded using the function to read pixels off the screen but I'm not sure when to use it. First I thought about when loading a texture, analyze its limits (the pixels that might collide and not all the pixels) into a certain pattern and then when a grid of a certain PNG crosses another - analyze if the pixels of both textures in the certain X and Y are meant to be touching each other and colliding. I'm not sure how to do that (using glReadPixels or any other function to read pixels off of the PNG texture which ISN'T on screen yet). Any idea to make Pixel-per-pixel 2D collision ? OR a better 2D collision detection algorithm ?

Comment: Instead of `SOIL` (which is old and unmaintained),  I recommend you to use `OpenIL/DevIL/ResIL` but mostly `FreeImage`

Comment: Tried using DevIL, not working for me for some reason and I compile just fine :P
When I've downloaded freeimage i found only C++ source codes and none of them written in C.

Comment: FreeImage has C++ binding of course, but I'm using it in a pure C environment, FI is written purely in C. Download the PDF doc from their website and see for yourself. Also: you can find several examples on how to use it on Stack overflow too.

Comment: @PeterVaro Then can you give me the download of it ? I found the headers with their code written in C++ files. I need the C headers with the C code.

Comment: you can find everything [here](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To read only part of an image as a texture, one method is to read the entire image and load it into a texture. You can then create a new texture using the [`glTexSubImage2D()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) call. This is particularly convenient for sprites because you can call it repeatedly, changing the x and y offset to pull out the different frames of your animation.

2) Collision detection is a big topic and too broad to answer in a single question like this. You should look up [QuadTrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or if you're working in 3D, [KdTrees](https://duckduckgo.com/Kd-tree)). They partition the space so you can compare the bounding boxes of your various sprites efficiently. Once you find 2 sprites whose bounding boxes overlap, you can test them more closely to see if they overlap. Usually you can use some trick such as blitting their 1-bit masks to the same small texture (with the proper relative offsets) using an AND-like blend mode (where the output is 1 only when both inputs are 1) and seeing if any pixels in the resulting texture are turned on. That way you're only scanning an area that is at most the size of the 2 textures, and not the entire window.

To expand on what I'm trying to describe above with the AND-like blend mode, you have the following scenario:

2 1-bit sprite masks where each pixel is 0 if the sprite does not cover that pixel and 1 if it does. These are the input textures.

1 1-bit output texture where the 2 sprites will be drawn

For each pixel of the output, you have 4 possibilities for the inputs:

- 0-0 : both sprites are transparent at this output pixel, so they
  don't touch here
- 1-0, 0-1: One sprite is transparent at this pixel,
  the other is not. Hence, they don't overlap
- 1-1 : Both sprites are    solid at this output pixel, so there's a
  collision

If you write it as a truth table, it's the same as ANDing the 2 masks:

```
  | 0 | 1 |
--+---+---+-
0 | 0 | 0 |
--+---+---+-
1 | 0 | 1 |
--+---+---+-
```

Comment: First, thanks alot for the answer. 
Second, I didn't understand one thing. In answer number 2, what do you mean "XOR-like blend mode and seeing if any pixels in the resulting texture are turned on". I know what XOR is but can you give me an example for knowing if "pixels in the resulting texture are turned on"?

Comment: I was thinking of something along the lines of a blend mode where the 2 inputs are 1-bit per pixel masks, and the output at each pixel is something like 0 if neither or only 1 of the masks is 1, but 1 when both masks are 1. So technically, I guess it's an AND operator. I was thinking of XOR because I've used that for other similar things in the past. XOR is like AND except when both inputs are 0 the output is also 1. I'll update answer to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean NOT(XOR)? XOR is only 1 when the input is 0 and 1 or 1 and 0 ? I still didn't get it. Can you write a small piece of example code ?

Comment: See my additional explanation above.

Comment: I still didn't understand what two masks. I just thought about getting a texture into an array of pixels with ALPHA (transprency) and then it would be really simple for me

Comment: Don't worry too much about the details, then. If you've got something that works, go with that. I was just offering one possible solution, but there are many others.

Comment: It's not working because I don't know how to get a texture into an array of pixels with Alpha. If I would know it would be helpful. So either that or can you, please, explain more about the 2nd answer?

Comment: You should post another question about that, as it would be too long to describe in the comments here.